# Unable to find /usr/lib/debug/modules/...vmlinux file for debugging dump file with crash utility

Tags: kernel, crash, debug

I need to debug a vmcore dump file using crash utility, but i don't see a debug vmlinux in my `/usr/lib/debug/modules/` path.

Actually in my system, the **modules** directory is not present under /usr/lib/debug/ directory.

I tried installing the debugging symbols using the following links:

https://drgn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_debugging_symbols.html

https://hadibrais.wordpress.com/2017/03/13/installing-ubuntu-kernel-debugging-symbols/

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/linux-on-systems?topic=linuxonibm/liacf/oprofkernelsymrhel.html

But it fails to install debug symbols.

The below two commands are final commands to install debug symbols:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r)-dbgsym
sudo apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r)-dbg
```

But the above command fails to install debug symbols with following message:

```
E: Unable to locate package linux-image-6.0.2-dbgsym
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-image-6.0.2-dbgsym
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-image-6.0.2-dbgsym
```

System details:

Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

linux kernel version : 6.0.2

Please advice on how to get the debug vmlinux.

Answer (score 0):

You've installed an unsupported mainline kernel to Ubuntu 18.04.

The `sudo apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r)-dbgsym` command tries to install a package corresponding the running kernel (`uname -r`) and fails.

Obviously because there is no 6.0.2 kernel in Ubuntu repositories.

You have some options:

1. Use a supported Ubuntu kernel. In this case the commands should work.
2. Install `dbgsym` from the place you got the 6.0.2 image if there is one.
3. Build a kernel from source with enabled `dbgsym`.